# How to import packages from node modules in Javascript? Not using build tools

Tags: javascript, node-modules

I have installed Vue in my project using NPM and I am now trying to use it in a javascript file called main.vue.js.

However when I am trying to import the Vue module I get this error in the browser:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/vue.esm 404 (Not Found)
```

main.vue.js:

```
import Vue from './vue.esm'

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        message: 'Hello Vue!'
    }
});

export {app}
```

I've also tried importing from

```
../node_modules/vue/dist/vue.esm
```

and even from root and neither work.

In my html file I am using a script tag in head:

```
<script type="module" src="main.vue.js"></script>
```

I'm not using any build tools at the moment, I'm just wanting to do this with plain javascript and modules support in Chrome browser.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, server was not serving node_modules as I specified root as one directory lower than node_modules.